# Python Histogram with monthly frequencies

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I need to make a histogram in Python using matplotlib. My data is a tuple of frequencies of monthly occurring events as below where x-axis should show the months and y-axis should show the frequencies. Can anyone help please?

```
[('Jun-07', 10),
 ('Jun-08', 15),
 ('Jun-09', 16),
 ('Nov-07', 17),
 ('Nov-08', 16),
 ('Nov-09', 14),
 ('May-11', 16),
 ('May-10', 18),
 ('May-13', 14),
 ('May-12', 14),
 ('May-14', 12),
 ('Jun-14', 10),
 ('Jun-11', 14),
 ('Jun-10', 19),
 ('Jun-13', 13),
 ('Jun-12', 14),
 ('Feb-09', 10),
 ('Nov-14', 10),
 ('Nov-13', 12),
 ('Nov-12', 13)]
```

Comment: Did you try something so far? Could you show us?

Comment: yes, I was able to make a bar chart from the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the histogram relative to the months, you should do something like :

```
import calendar
dmonths = dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

list1 = [('Jun-07', 10),
 ('Jun-08', 15),
 ('Jun-09', 16),
 ('Nov-07', 17),
 ('Nov-08', 16),
 ('Nov-09', 14),
 ('May-11', 16),
 ('May-10', 18),
 ('May-13', 14),
 ('May-12', 14),
 ('May-14', 12),
 ('Jun-14', 10),
 ('Jun-11', 14),
 ('Jun-10', 19),
 ('Jun-13', 13),
 ('Jun-12', 14),
 ('Feb-09', 10),
 ('Nov-14', 10),
 ('Nov-13', 12),
 ('Nov-12', 13)]

list2 = [dmonths[x[0][:3]] for x in list1]
list3 = [x[1] for x in list1]

plt.hist(np.array(list2), bins=np.array(range(1,12)), weights=np.array(list3))
```

The first two lines give a lookup table from months to integers. Afterwards, you only need to extract the names of the months, convert them into integers, and plot the histogram with the values as weights.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def histogram():
    set_list = set(link_list)
    return [(idx, link_list.count(idx)) for idx in set_list]

xx, yy = [datetime.strptime(idx[0],'%b-%y') for idx in his_sorted],
         [idx[1] for idx in his_sorted]
plt.bar(xx, yy, width = 50)
```

Comment: `link_list` and `his_sorted` are not defined, and you don't use the function `histogram()` you wrote. Moreover, I think you need to import the `datetime` module